# Array to String Exception Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, exception

**CategoryApiController.php**

```
    public function posts($id){<br>
        $category_data = Category::find($id);        
        $posts=$category_data->posts();
}
```

**Category.php (Model)**

```
 public function posts(){
        return Post::whereJsonContains('category_id',$this->attributes['id'])->get();
```

I am trying to get the Posts for Perticular Category which is stored in Category_id as JSON. If I replace **$this->attributes['id']** with **'3'** which is a static value, I get the data m looking for, but I want it to be dynamic. However **$this->attributes['id']** ll fetch the category id for ex (3) successfully, but it's not accepting as an argument and returns an Empty Array.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

Please Help Me Out

Comment: Hi and welcome. You might want to revisit your post and work a bit on the markup as currently it is very hard to read due formatting and typos. A good post might result in more answers than in its current state.

From what I see Im wondering what you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. You probably forgot to add array casting.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting.

When you add this, you should get something like this in you:

```
// Category.php

protected $casts = [
     'category_ids' => 'array'
];


// CategoryApiController@posts

$model->update(['category_ids' => [1, 2, 3]);
```

2. The second problem is the data types.
   Your array stores strings and you pass a number, so it does not work.
   Notice in point one I showed you how to save in integer. So if you save in integer, your code will work without changing this line.

Post::whereJsonContains('category_id', 1) // int

Post::whereJsonContains('category_id', '1') // string

e.g. `whereJsonContains('category_id', (string)$this->attributes['id'])` // pass string